# Issue in concurrently running 2 instances of the same SSIS package in SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I created a basic SSIS package in SQL Server 2012 for testing concurrency using SQL Server agent jobs. I want to be able to run copies of the same package as part of different jobs.

Package Design:
There is a variable in the package called ThreadID which represent the thread in which the package is running. This variable is included in the configuration XML file as below:
-
1

There is only one task in the package. It is a simple Exec SQL Task that passes ThreadID to a stored procedure and the stored procedure writes the ThreadID in a SQL Server table.

Result:
Everything works fine when I execute one copy of the package in VS IDE or SQL Server agent job. The issue shows itself when I run two instances of the same package package concurrently in 2 different SQL agent jobs. Each job has a copy of the package file and a configuration XML file. One XML file has ThreadID=1 and another one has ThreadID=2. What I see in the SQL Server table is ThreadID of the job that first started. The table contains all 1 when I start the first job and then the second job. It will be all 2 when I start the second job first.

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: To restate: You have an SSIS package that uses an XML configuration file. The contents of that file are assigned to a variable which is then used as a parameter for an Execute SQL Task. There are two copies of this package?, one which points to 1.dtsconfig and 2.dtsconfig. When run singly, you see the values as expected. However, running both at the same time result in duplicate values.

Comment: @abiete, post the SQL of your stored procedure please.

Comment: Yes. 
Here is the body of stored procedure:
Create Procedure [dbo].[WriteThreadID] @ThreadID int as
 set nocount on

 INSERT INTO [dbo].[DW_Load_Log] (ThreadID)
 VALUES (@ThreadID)
go